# javascript regex replace at the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have following string:

> `text = '20 as a % of 50'`

I need to replace it using a regular expression, the result should be:

> `'20 / 50 * 100'`

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give another example? I can't get the regular pattern from this one

Comment: sounds like you're trying to hack an "are you a human" portion of a form ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created an example here: http://regexr.com?2tfam

You can match with `(\d+) as a % of (\d+)` and replace with `$1 / $2 * 100`.

```
var a="text = '20 as a % of 50'";
alert(a.replace(/(\d+) as a % of (\d+)/, '$1 / $2 * 100'));
```

I also created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MD35v/).

**EDIT**: If your text between the numbers will change, you can use this regex:

```
(\d+)[%a-zA-Z ]+(\d+)
```

It assumes that the operator is % and between the numbers only letters and spaces can occur.

Comment: thanks, and what if between two numbers can be chars, for example 100 usd as a % of 200 usd, and i need to keep usd in str?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you,

```
var str="20 as a % of 50"; 
var patt1=/(\d)+/g;
alert(str.match(patt1)[0]+ "/"+ str.match(patt1)[1] + "* 100");
```